# Parity node mysteriously shutting down by itself

Tags: parity

I noticed that my Parity node keeps shutting down by itself every 15 minutes or so.

I am running it using this command:

```
/usr/bin/parity --jsonrpc-interface=all --jsonrpc-port=8545 --log-file=/root/parity/parity.log
```

A snapshot of my log files as below:

```
2018-11-30 13:18:39 UTC Starting Parity-Ethereum/v2.1.7-stable-126208c-20181128/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.30.1
2018-11-30 13:18:39 UTC Keys path /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/ethereum
2018-11-30 13:18:39 UTC DB path /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d
2018-11-30 13:18:39 UTC State DB configuration: fast
2018-11-30 13:18:39 UTC Operating mode: active
2018-11-30 13:18:39 UTC Configured for Foundation using Ethash engine
2018-11-30 13:18:41 UTC Removed existing file '/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc'.
2018-11-30 13:18:42 UTC Updated conversion rate to Îž1 = US$113.46 (41969896 wei/gas)
2018-11-30 13:18:46 UTC Public node URL: enode://<somenode>@<somehost>
2018-11-30 13:18:51 UTC Snapshot initializing (5 chunks restored)  #2427249   15/25 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:19:01 UTC Snapshot initializing (13 chunks restored)  #2427249   20/25 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:19:11 UTC Snapshot initializing (19 chunks restored)  #2427249   22/25 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:19:21 UTC Snapshot initializing (25 chunks restored)  #2427249   23/25 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:19:31 UTC Snapshot initializing (29 chunks restored)  #2427249   23/25 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:19:41 UTC Snapshot initializing (35 chunks restored)  #2427249   26/50 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:19:51 UTC Snapshot initializing (40 chunks restored)  #2427249   25/25 peers      1 MiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:20:01 UTC Snapshot initializing (45 chunks restored)  #2427249   28/50 peers      1 MiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:20:11 UTC Snapshot initializing (49 chunks restored)  #2427249   30/50 peers      1 MiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   22 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:25:50 UTC Starting Parity-Ethereum/v2.1.7-stable-126208c-20181128/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.30.1
2018-11-30 13:25:50 UTC Keys path /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/ethereum
2018-11-30 13:25:50 UTC DB path /root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d
2018-11-30 13:25:50 UTC State DB configuration: fast
2018-11-30 13:25:50 UTC Operating mode: active
2018-11-30 13:25:50 UTC Configured for Foundation using Ethash engine
2018-11-30 13:25:52 UTC Removed existing file '/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/jsonrpc.ipc'.
2018-11-30 13:25:53 UTC Updated conversion rate to Îž1 = US$113.61 (41914484 wei/gas)
2018-11-30 13:25:57 UTC Public node URL: enode://<somenode>@<somehost>
2018-11-30 13:25:57 UTC Snapshot initializing (2 chunks restored)  #2427249   15/25 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:26:07 UTC Snapshot initializing (10 chunks restored)  #2427249   15/25 peers     80 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:26:17 UTC Snapshot initializing (16 chunks restored)  #2427249   19/25 peers    781 KiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:26:27 UTC Snapshot initializing (22 chunks restored)  #2427249   22/25 peers      3 MiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:26:37 UTC Snapshot initializing (27 chunks restored)  #2427249   22/25 peers      3 MiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:26:47 UTC Snapshot initializing (33 chunks restored)  #2427249   24/25 peers      3 MiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
2018-11-30 13:26:57 UTC Snapshot initializing (38 chunks restored)  #2427249   27/50 peers      3 MiB chain  224 MiB db  0 bytes queue   11 KiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,    0 req/s,    0 Âµs
```

I have set my Parity node as a service so everytime it mysteriously shuts down, it will boot up again but whenever it boots up, it will keep redoing the same process and not progress to downloading other blocks.

How do I fix this silently self-terminating node ?

Comment: There is no silent termination - either it quits itself or the system forces the shutdown of the process. Have you checked your system logs if you have anything related? My guesses would be out of memory or similar.

Comment: Yes you are right. It seems to run out of memory. How much RAM do I need to allocate it and how do I scale the memory ? I am using a Cloud instance with 1 GB RAM.

Comment: I just set the --cache-size=16 and it still crashes with Out of memory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardware recommendations [from Parity for a full node](https://wiki.parity.io/FAQ#what-are-the-parity-ethereum-disk-space-needs-and-overall-hardware-requirements) are:

> 4GB RAM and an SSD drive and at least 100GB free space

Your comments indicate that you are only using 1 GB of RAM which is too little to get a full node syncing.

You might be better off with these hardware limitations trying to run a light client:

> **Light Node**
>
> Running a light node using the flag --light does not require to
>   download and perform validation of the whole blockchain. A light node
>   relies on full node peers to receive block headers and verify
>   transactions. It is therefore far less resource demanding than a full
>   node.
>
> A computer or mobile phone with single core CPU, 512MB RAM and an HDD
>   with 128MB free space are recommended to run a light node.